sitemap.xml missing tags when run through schedule
I have installed: spatie/laravel-sitemap composer packages
For caching is responsible: spatie/laravel-responsecache
Sitemap generation command:
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Spatie\Crawler\Crawler;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;

class GenerateSitemap extends Command
{
    ...

    protected $signature = 'sitemap:generate';

    ...

    public function handle()
    {
        ...Here is logging...

        SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
                        ->configureCrawler(function (Crawler $crawler) {
                            $crawler->setUserAgent('Sitemaper');
                        })
                        ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
    }
}


Scheduler:
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
         $schedule->command('sitemap:generate')->hourly();
    }
}

Cron: * * * * * cd /var/www/projectname && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
When I run command using php artisan sitemap:generate everything is fine and I see 15 pages, when it run through cron- from 0 to 5 and most of the time output is different.
I tried:

Remove cache;
Set cache bypass header in $crawler and .env
I made sure that APP_URL is correct in .env


Edit:
If switch hourly() to everyMinute() sitemap is generated the right way. But that is not a solution as generating it every minute is pretty useless usage of resources

Laravel version and laravel-sitemap version??

laravel/framework: 10.48.16;
spatie/laravel-sitemap: 7.2.1

you want it daily()?

Yes, and I already made it daily. My problem is not the frequency. My problem is that it gives different result every time.

what you expect and what you get?

I'm expecting- to get the same result on every run (right now it is 16 items/links) in sitemap on every run. Instead I'm getting unpredictable results (yesterday 6 or 8 items/links, today 16 items/links)

do you use JS on the site? if so this can change stuff, on config, use 'execute_javascript' => true,
